# Are there any differences in docking procedures between ISS and manned capsules vs. unmanned capsules?

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight, soyuz-spacecraft, dragon-v2, uncrewed-spaceflight

The Russian Soyuz has an extensive history in docking with ISS with both manned and unmanned capsules. SpaceX just recently demonstrated manned-capsule docking with ISS with a history of unmanned successes.

Are there any significant differences between unmanned vs. manned in either of these programs? I'm curious not just about procedures, but if there are any differences with timelines or rates as well.

Comment: Soyuz and Progress dock automatically.  In case of equipment failure, manual docking is possible. For a Progress, this is a remote control.

Comment: posts containing "kurs" https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=kurs

Answer (score 5):

The various visiting vehicles connect with the ISS in different fashions.

Soyuz, Progress, and ATV use the [Kurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurs_(docking_navigation_system)) docking system for automated docking, but with a manual override.

Dragon V1, HTV, and Cygnus, [berth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docking_and_berthing_of_spacecraft) at the station. They arrive close to the station, and then the CanadaArm2 grapples the vehicle, moves it to the berthing port, and then the vehicle berths with the station.

The Space Shuttle used a [PMA (Pressurized Mating Adapter)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressurized_Mating_Adapter) to dock to the station.

The new vehicles, Dragon Crew (V2), CST-100, Dream Chaser will dock to a PMA with the addition of an [IDA (International Docking Adapter)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Docking_Adapter).